# Using dplyr::summarise with dplyr::across and purrr::map to sum across columns with the same prefix

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a data frame where I want to sum column values with the same prefix to produce a new column. My current problem is that it's not taking into account my `group_by` variable and returning identical values. Is part of the problem the .cols variable I'm selecting in the across function?

**Sample data**

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

set.seed(10)

dat <- data.frame(id = rep(1:2, 5), 
                  var1.pre  = rnorm(10), 
                  var1.post = rnorm(10),
                  var2.pre  = rnorm(10), 
                  var2.post = rnorm(10) 
                   ) %>% 
  mutate(index = id) 

var_names = c("var1", "var2")
```

[image]

**What I've tried**

```
sumfunction <- map(
  var_names,
  ~function(.){
    sum(dat[glue("{.x}.pre")], dat[glue("{.x}.post")], na.rm = TRUE)
  }
) %>% 
  setNames(var_names)

dat %>% 
 group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(
    across(
      .cols  = index,
      .fns   = sumfunction, 
      .names = "{.fn}"
    )
  ) %>% 
  ungroup
```

[image]

**Desired output**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever operations across multiple columns get complicated, we could pivot:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

  dat %>% 
    pivot_longer(-c(id, index),
                 names_to = c(".value", "name"), 
                 names_sep = "\\.") %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(var1 = sum(var1), var2=sum(var2))
```

```
   id  var1  var2
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 -2.32 -5.55
2     2  1.11 -9.54
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution! Within summarise, you can use across:

summarise(
    across(
      .cols = var_names,
      .fns = ~ sum(.x)
    )
This makes it even more efficient! Thank you again!

Answer (score 5):

For this and similar problems I made the 'dplyover' package (it is not on CRAN). Here we can use `dplyover::across2()` to loop over two series of columns, first, all columns ending with `"pre"` and second all columns ending with `"post"`. To get the names correct we can use  `.names = "{pre}"` to get the common prefix of both series of columns.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dplyover) # https://timteafan.github.io/dplyover/

dat %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(across2(ends_with("pre"),
                    ends_with("post"),
                    ~ sum(c(.x, .y)),
                    .names = "{pre}"
                    )
            )

#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>      id  var1  var2
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1 -2.32 -5.55
#> 2     2  1.11 -9.54
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I like `dplyover` package very much. Unfortunately I am not using it frequently so sometimes I just forget that it exists. :-)